# Caffeine read/write taking longer under high load

Tags: caffeine, caffeine-cache

This is how I build my Caffeine Cache in Spring boot:

```
Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .initialCapacity(200000)
                .maximumSize(200000)
                .expireAfterWrite(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .scheduler(Scheduler.systemScheduler())
                .executor(caffeineWriteClientConnectionPool(cacheSpec))
                .recordStats(() -> caffeineMetrics)
                .writer(new CacheWriter<Object, Object>() {});
```

I use the following Synchronous methods:

```
cache.getAllPresent() -> fetch all keys present in cache if not fallback to distributed cache/db and then add the key to the caffeine cache
cache.putAll() -> a key is added to the caffeine cache when its missed
```

When the cache load is high, I see get/put time increasing(>100ms) and this is making me think if these calls should be behind hystrix but I am think that's gonna be an overkill spinning up a thread for an in-memory search?

Also, I see the GC happening pretty often and I believe this might be impacting the read/write time. Any suggestions/best practices on setting up the GC or any other general suggestion I can do to improve the latency? thanks

Comment: To reduce locking and latency, use `getAll` with a loader instead of a racy read and explicit put. This avoids redundant work (cache stampede) and reduces locking. An async cache can better optimize bulk loads, but generally at only a slight improvement.

Comment: getAll/putAll might call anywhere between 1-100 keys at a time under high load. I see the ```getAll``` method under the hood calls ```getAllPresent``` and then loads the keys that are not present. If a key is absent in Caffeine, the logic falls back to the distributed cache/db where I explicitly add the missing keys using ```putAll``` to Caffeine. After considering these, do you still think that using ```getAll``` would reduce latency/locking or suggest using Async?

Comment: On that's right. In async, it is able to be smarter by inserting proxy futures that are filled when a single bulk call is made. This way only bulk call is made and subsequent calls obtain an in-flight future for those keys. Unfortunately we can't do similar in a sync cache for `getAll`, but you can use `AsyncCache.synchronous()` to have a sync view. That might help, e.g. [doordash](https://doordash.engineering/2018/08/03/avoiding-cache-stampede-at-doordash/) reported an 87% latency reduction by avoiding stampedes.

Comment: I'll try implementing the ```getAll``` with a loader using the ```AsyncCache.synchronous()``` view and see if it helps improve the performance. Thanks!

Comment: @BenManes While looking at the loader for ```getAll``` in ```AsyncCache.synchronous()``` view, the loader function accepts the keys as an argument and return the values. But the L2 cache/db as the fallback methods require more info/arguments such as the logger which is initialized with the data from the client request and some other flags, do you think this is achievable using the Loader function? It seems I have the implement the locking/proxy futures? any suggestions please?

Comment: The lamda can capture the contextual state, so you can pass it through there. The cache only stores they `key` => `future` mapping, but the lambda function can capture the outer scope, e.g. `var userId = 123; cache.getAll(dataKeys, keys -> load(keys, userId))`

Comment: @BenManes the first test on the ```getAll``` method in the ```AsyncCache.synchronous()``` view seems to perform a lot better, thanks for the help

Comment: that’s great! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @BenManes Appreciate your efforts in answering all the questions, using AsyncCache resolved the latency issues we had before but one question I have though is using the AsyncCache using a thread pool seems to be an overkill as we are already calling the cache from a different thread pool thread, so do you think using the Cache ```getAll``` with a loader would give almost the same performance without the additional thread overhead? I am worried that we might see cache stampede with using Cache with loader? Wanted to know your thoughts before I test. Thanks

Comment: You can specify the threadpool used by the cache or return a future from the loader that it will store. You could try using a same thread executor (Runnable::run) which would probably give you the results you want.

Comment: I was able to do it and everything's working as expected, thanks a lot for the suggestions. you're awesome!